# I want to change background image of my wordpress site on particular post type

Tags: theme-development

let say my post slug is /happypost

This is code of page.php from theme editor

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php do_action('flatsome_before_page' ); ?>
<?php do_action('flatsome_after_header'); ?>
<div id="wrapper">
    
    
    <div id="main" class="<?php flatsome_main_classes();  ?>">
            
    
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
        
    

    </div><!-- #main -->
    <footer id="footer" class="footer-wrapper">

    <?php do_action('flatsome_footer'); ?>

</footer><!-- .footer-wrapper -->
</div><!-- #wrapper -->
<?php do_action( 'flatsome_after_page' ); ?>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress has a very complete Template Hierarchy. For more detailed explanation, visit this article: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Basically, to define the layout for this post-type, you can create a file in the theme directory named: single-{post-type}.php

In your example: single-happypost.php

Cheers!

Comment: can you please tell me how to create new file in theme directory should i need to create it by going to my cpanel >> file manager ??

Comment: Well, your theme has the page.php , you need to create this new page in the same place in cpanel -> file manager. And then you will edit the HTML of this page as you want. I don't know what server you have, but if you have cpanel, it is easy to find a tutorial.

Like this for example: https://www.doteasy.com/cpanel-hosting-features/cpanel-file-manager-creating-a-new-file-or-new-folder